# how can i detect if it's a 404 page in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a client component that checks the authentication state and is incorporated into app/layout.tsx. The objective is to determine if the user is logged in or not. If not, the user is redirected to the login page if the current URL path is not /login. If the user is logged in, they are redirected to / if the current URL path is /login.

Here's the code:

**(Firebase)**

```js
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {  // if user is logged in
    if (path === "/login") {
      router.push("/");
    }
  } else { // if user is not logged in
    if (path !== "/login") {
      router.push("/login");
    }
  }
});
```

Notice that using this code, the user cannot access any 404 pages if they aren't logged in. The code will redirect the user to the login page if they do so, which I don't want. To prevent this, I need to detect if it's a 404 page.

So, how do I check if it's a 404 page with Next.js 13?

Let me know if you need any additional info to solve the issue.

Comment: Next.js provides the components **_error.js** and **_error.tsx**. Those would make it possible to fix your issue.

Comment: but the **error.tsx** is for errors to handle. not for the not found pages. those are handled by the **not-found.tsx** file. isn't it?

Comment: it is a bigger effort, but it is possible with it. You need to create context and and and

Comment: is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: It is not a that big effort, but you need to read the documentation I guess and look for other examples.

Comment: I mean it should be worth it

Comment: whatever I have found about 404 pages in the doc, explains how to handle a 404 page. how to render a custom UI. but I can't find anything explaining how to detect the status code of the current page. I mean, if Next.js is handling the 404 pages for us, they surely can provide us with this info somehow

Comment: Isn't layout.js suppose to have layout stuff? Maybe you could put this authentication process in the app.tsx and run it to every page you have. Does path has a value when the 404 page is rendered? If yes, cant you use it?

Comment: @PratikDev Check out my answer, I hope it helps you

Comment: @WilliamRizzi I think the layout stuff also can have authentication logic. but that isn't the main issue. I can surely move the logic to **page.tsx** if that's a best practice. and the path has the URL path for the 404 page. i.e `/sjfldjsljsdf` and `/erojcojlsaeo` both will be counted as 404 pages. so I can't check the path for the 404 page

Comment: You could have a list of routes inside your application and check if the path match any of then. Isn't clear as something out of the box but should work.

Comment: @WilliamRizzi that also won't do the job as my app will have dynamic routes

Answer (score 0):

Usually, redirection or authentication is handled in middleware files or a wrapper files. if you still want to follow your approach, you should manually defined all the routes in your app

```
const routes=["route1",....]


onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {  // if user is logged in
    if (path === "/login") {
      router.push("/");
    }
  } else { // if user is not logged in
    // if not logged in and visiting a valid path
    if (routes.includes(path)) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't define all my routes manually cause my app will have dynamic routes. and handling the authentication in a wrapper file will make my whole app client side (as the authentication file needs to be a client component). but what's the idea of middleware files?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `App` component you should check if `router.pathname` is pointing to an error page and if so, immediately return `Component` from props

```
_app.tsx

const App = ({ Component, pageProps, router }: AppProps) => {
  if (router.pathname === '/_error') {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
  }

  // Return `Component` wrapped in your layout with providers, error boundaries, etc
}
```